# Set shape of only some points in altair scatter plot

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to set the shape for one variable in this altair scatterplot (since I am dealing with live data, I do not know every possible domain value), therefore I am trying to set the value for only two of those values.

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_point(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    shape=alt.Shape(
        'Origin',
        # scale=alt.Scale(
        #     domain=['USA', 'Europe'],
        #     range=['circle', 'square']
        # )
    )
)
```

This returns the following plot:

[image]

If however, I am uncommenting the scale parameter, the third element in the legend and the plot disappears:

[image]

How can I set the shape for a subset of my variable (and not loose the remaining variables in the plot)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_point(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    shape=alt.condition(
        alt.FieldOneOfPredicate(
            'Origin',
            ['USA', 'Europe']
        ),
        alt.Shape('Origin:N').scale(
            domain=['USA', 'Europe'],
            range=['circle', 'square']
        ),
        alt.value('triangle')
    )
)
```

[image]

If you also want the shape in the legend, I think it is easier to modify the underlying data:

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()
alt.Chart(source.assign(shape=source['Origin'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ['USA', 'Europe'] else 'Other'))).mark_point(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    shape=alt.Shape('shape:N').sort(['USA', 'Europe', 'Other'])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also have an idea on how to deal with this situation if I do not not beforehand (working on live data) the possible values of shape and if I do not want to loose any of them (with something like "Other")?

Comment: Do you mean not grouping them together as "Other", but instead having distinct shapes? In that case I would probably set the domain to a list that has USA and Europe first and then all other items dynamically added from the unique values in Origin; something like `['USA', 'Europe'] + [item for item in source['Origin'].unique() if item not in ['USA', 'Europe']]`. You can skip setting the range altogether if that is what you want.

Comment: Thas is almost what I need. The problem is that I only know the first symbol which should be a triangle pointing to the right, and the rest is more or less randomly distributed (just trying to avoid other triangles in order to not mix them up in the plot). Example: `USA` referring to triangle-right, the rest is custom but the code for the plot should be robust in case a new category appears with a data update.

Comment: I think the solution above should work for that if you combine it with also adding a list for the range starting with `'triangle-right'` (which can be arbitrarily long I think and if there are fewer categories, only those will be used)

Comment: that is great, thank you very much for your help